# Convert/Cast XNode to XDocument

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml

This might be a very simple question for many but I was wondering how to convert XNode to XDocument. The method is expecting an XDocument but since it was meant for a specific element I would be required to loop as can be seen below. And then it would result that it will be a XNode which is not valid.

```
Dim xDoc = XDocument.Parse(oXMLResponse)
For Each item In xDoc.Descendants().Nodes()
   ParseXmlToObject(item)
next
```

Comment: Any chance you can convert this method to accept XNode instead of XDocument?

Comment: I believe this can _not_ be done (by casting) since the XDocument inherits XNode and not vice versa.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I have followed your advice and changed it to XElement since I had a case where that was needed. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for my C#, not VB. Can you try to create a new XElement inside your loop:

```
XElement xElem = new XElement(item.Name, item.InnerXml);
XElement[] xElemArray = new XElement[1];
xElemArray[0] = xElem;
```

And then you got a XDocument with:

```
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(xElemArray);
```

But that's not an effective solution!

Comment: You're totally correct and thus I have decided to change the method to accept XElement so that I will definitely have a problem.

Comment: It must be a better solution yes! Glad you find the solution with Sergey's comment and this answer.